# convert Mysql timestamp date in Date object localized

Tags: mysql, date, jpa

I have an issue. I have to save Date object in Mysql database through JPA. To do that I use this annotation

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date date;
```

When I try to add an element into the mysql database everything works like a charm. This is an example of a date saved in a TIMESTAMP field 2014-06-09 05:00:00. When I retrieve date from the database I get `Mon Jun 09 05:00:00 CEST 2014`. How can I set the format, localization and everything else of the date I get from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set the format when you retrieve the Date from the DB; the retrieved Date has no time zone or formatting information associated with it. What you're seeing is just the `toString` representation  of that Date, which converts the Date to a format that's a bit more readable. But that doesn't actually change the Date's contents and you can still format it any way you like. You can use the `DateFormat` class (I believe in the `java.util` package) to get it in the format you want. The javadocs are quite good and will explain everything.